# Datagridview with date-header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with appointment information. There are four columns `Name`, `Appointment Type`, `Appointment Date`, `Appointment Time`. I need to find the day of any appointment and display a header for each day with the day and date with. It would look like this:

```
**Monday 07/03/2016**
Amy      New     13:00
**Tuesday 08/03/2016**
Betty    Second  14:30
Sally    New     16:00
```

Comment: Ok, so whats the question or problem (knowing that someone will edit the text and add some and make me look stupid later) ..

Comment: I need each row with new date to display with header with day and date then each appointment for that date until date changes then new row with header, sorry if I'm being unclear

Comment: You havent posted a problem.  Or a question. You've made a series of statements. We dont code for you, we help you work out whats wrong.

Comment: Here is a [good link](http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx) for you.

Comment: @PSC hope this helps :P

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one headerline in a `DataGridView`.
I would suggest highlighting (or better darklight) the DateRows in your DataGrid.

**Here is a quick sample how this would look like:**
[image]

What did I do:

First I added a Class which describes your Data.

```
public class Entry
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } //Combine the Date and the Time 
    public string AppointmentType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;  }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + AppointmentType + " " + DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Then I created a List for debugging:

```
        List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>(); //This is your Input

        entries.Add(new Entry()
        {
            Name = "Betty",
            AppointmentType = "New",
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        });

        entries.Add(new Entry()
        {
            Name = "Sally",
            AppointmentType = "New",
            DateTime = DateTime.Now
        });

        entries.Add(new Entry()
        {
            Name = "Amy",
            AppointmentType = "New",
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-15)
        });
```

You might get your Data from elsewhere...
Then parse it to a `List<Entry>`.

Then I sorted the Data:

```
entries.Sort(new Comparison<Entry>((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.DateTime, y.DateTime))); -- Ascending

entries.Sort(new Comparison<Entry>((x, y) => -DateTime.Compare(x.DateTime, y.DateTime))); --Descending
```

Then group 'em by Date:

```
        List<Entry> newList = new List<Entry>();
        //Now adding the new "headers" 
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dateOfAppointment = (DateTime)entries[i].DateTime;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                if (dateOfAppointment.Date != entries[i - 1].DateTime.Date)//Not the same Date as the previous one => Add new Header with Date
                {
                    newList.Add(new Entry() {DateTime = dateOfAppointment});
                }
            }                
            //Else: we add the entry under the current date cause its still the same...
            newList.Add(entries[i]);//Add Entry
        }
```

Last but not least fill your `DataGridView`:

```
//Fill the Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < newList.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = newList[i].DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newList[i].Name)) //=> Is not a Header
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = newList[i].DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = newList[i].Name;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = newList[i].AppointmentType;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newList[i].DateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = newList[i].DateTime.ToString("dddd dd.MM.yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = newList[i].Name = null;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = newList[i].AppointmentType = null;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
```